# HTTP Static file handler keeps showing the directory list

Tags: http, go, static-files

When I implement a static server handler, if I access to root path, it will show the whole directory, like this:

[image: access to root folder]

My code is:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    port := flag.String("p", "3000", "port to serve on")
    directory := flag.String("d", ".", "the directory of static file to host")
    flag.Parse()

    http.Handle("/statics/", http.StripPrefix(strings.TrimRight("/statics/", "/"), http.FileServer(http.Dir(*directory))))

    log.Printf("Serving %s on HTTP port: %s\n", *directory, *port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+*port, nil))
}
```

go to : http://locahost:3000/statics/

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for? The resulting answer appers somewhat dirty to me, however. It basically consists of just checking if the currently requested resource is a Dir, or a File and handling it accordingly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589685/good-way-to-disable-directory-listing-with-http-fileserver-in-go

Comment: Uuuh, yes, this is what `Dir` does: [A Dir implements FileSystem using the native file system restricted to a specific directory tree](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Dir) What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @RickyA the problem is that most other servers default to returning a 404 when hitting a directory, which is a very sane default for security. Go doesn't offer a way to turn this off. Essentially the question's answer boils down to the last piece of the doc for `Dir`: "create a custom FileSystem implementation."

Comment: @RayfenWindspear that is an assumption. Maybe OP expects an index.html to be rendered, so I want to hear it from OP.

Comment: @RickyA not to seem rude, but it seems a safe assumption. Serving a "statics" dir with css, js, etc wouldn't normally have an index.html at the `statics/` level of the dir as it is just a container for the separate types of statics. But yes, an assumption nonetheless...

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I implemented a solution to my own repo related to the correct answer: https://github.com/hauxe/GoM/blob/master/http/filesystem_handler.go

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fortunately or not, the default behavior of [`http.FileServer`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) is that if the path denotes a directory without an `index.html` file, a directory listing will be served. And it does not provide a simple way to turn that off. But...

[`http.FileServer`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) operates on a *virtual* filesystem described by the [`http.FileSystem`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileSystem) interface.

This interface has a single method which tells how to open a file, and obtain an [`http.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#File) "view" of it:

```
type FileSystem interface {
        Open(name string) (File, error)
}
```

If you want to disable directory listing, all you have to do is provide your own implementation of `http.FileSystem` which when a directory is targeted, you simply report / return an error. That's all it takes.

Of course you don't have to do this all by yourself. You may create your own `FileSystem` which uses / utilizes [`http.Dir`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Dir), which is the default implementation that uses the native file system (restricted to a specific directory tree).

```
type myfs struct {
    http.Dir
}

func (m myfs) Open(name string) (result http.File, err error) {
    f, err := m.Dir.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    fi, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    if fi.IsDir() {
        // Return a response that would have been if directory would not exist:
        return m.Dir.Open("does-not-exist")
    }
    return f, nil
}
```

Using the above custom implementation:

```
handler := http.FileServer(myfs{http.Dir(*directory)})
http.Handle(
    "/statics/",
    http.StripPrefix(strings.TrimRight("/statics/", "/"), handler),
)
```

And that's all. Attempting to browse `http://locahost:3000/statics/` will result in the default response:

```
404 page not found
```

**Notes:**

The above implementation does a second `Dir.Open()` call to return an error, which is always the same. To "speed things up", we can store this response and just reuse it:

```
var notFoundFile, notFoundErr = http.Dir("dummy").Open("does-not-exist")
```

And when we detect a directory in our `myfs.Open()` method:

```
if fi.IsDir() {
    // Return a response that "belogns" to opening a non-existing folder:
    return notFoundFile, notFoundErr
}
```

Comment: +1 Straight to the point. Still seems odd that such a basic piece of functionality isn't builtin as an option.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear I agree, `http.FileServer` could use a little customization, in the public's best interest...